# stretching a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, flatten

I want to be able to turn

this:
[[[a],b],c]

into this:
[a,b,c]

with a constantly changing lists, so far I've done this:

```
a([[[A],B],C]).
strechList(List,C):-
    List=[H,T],
    append(T,List1,C),
    strechList(H,List1).
strechList(A,A).
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `[H,T]` is a list of only two elements. I'm supposing you meant, `[H|T]` which is a list whose first element (*head*) is `H` and *tail list* is `T`. Your rule `strechList(A, A).` says that any list is the stretch of itself, which doesn't sound correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That predicate is called 'flatten'. It's built-in if you're using SWI-Prolog.
Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383739/prolog-flatten-list) answer.

Comment: Thank you i'm actually using SWi-prolog this is really helpful. :)